# How to sum up this series and simplify yet another one?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, quantum-mechanics

Primarily, I would like to know what could be done with this series:

$$    \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{(n^2-1)^3}\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)^{2n}$$

As hardmath says in his comment, the series converges. I tried with Mathematica which gives for the sum 0.00526589. Is it possible to obtain some analytical result/approximation for the sum of the series?

Moreover, I would like to simplify the following sum:

$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)^{2n-3}}{n(n+1)^{2n+1}}\left[ \sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)^m\right]^2$$

Such sums appear in quantum mechanics when dealing with second order perturbation theory (the first mentioned case comes out when dealing with the Coulomb potential 1/r perturturbed by a k^2/r term). Any hints appreciated.

---

Update:
As hardmath says in his comment, in the 
"second series the finite inner sum (over m) is geometric, so it can be replaced by an explicit expression in terms of n".

This means that we can simplify the double sum into a single one:

$$ \frac1{4}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac1{n(n^2-1)}\left[1-2\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)^n+\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)^{2n}\right] $$

which is closer in form to the first mentioned.

Comment: What motivated these Questions?  Some context would be helpful to a Reader willing to provide useful information.

Comment: @hardmath Motivation added:-)

Comment: Thanks.  The first series converges (e.g. by comparison with the sum of $1/n^3$), but I suspect you want further information about "what could be done wit[h] this series".  Can you be more specific about what is known and what additional analysis would be useful to you?

Comment: @hardmath I further updated the question. Well, I would like to sum the series:-) I have little experience with series and it's hard for me to distinguish whether one can from a particular series expect to find it's sum, or only some estimates can be done.

Comment: For your first sum, I get 0.00526589019306362497, did you write it correctly? ISC found nothing for 0.00526589019306362497, so perhaps closed form evaluation will not be possible.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks. You are right, I copy-pasted another result. Sorry, what is ISC?

Comment: Inverse Symbolic Calculator ... http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au

Comment: @hardmath You wrote "by comparison with the sum of $1/n^3$. How to show it in the most simple way? Did you have in mind the ratio test or only to show $a_n<1/n^3$ for every $n$?

Comment: I had in mind showing $|a_n| \lt 1/(n^3 - 1)$ for every $n\gt 1$, so $|a_n| \lt 0.5/n^3$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: In your second series the finite inner sum (over $m$) is geometric, so it can be replaced by an explicit expression in terms of $n$.  Have you explored this?

Comment: @hardmath You're right with the geometric series, please see the updated the question. +1

Comment: By "simplifying the sum", do you mean finding a closed form for it?

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue Not necessarily - even a simplified version would be fine, so that further calculation (also numerical) is easier with it.